# How to delete a card on flutter from Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

I am building an app where I list upcoming football matches on cards, and store the matches in Firebase. the cards have a delete button on them, which make a popup asking for delete confirmation. How can I delete the card not only from the list, but firebase also.
This is the code for the card:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:foci_dev/model/next_matches.dart';
import 'package:foci_dev/pages/delete_page.dart';
import 'package:foci_dev/service/database_service.dart';

class DeleteCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final UpcomingMatch nextMatch;
  final cardId;
  DeleteCard(this.nextMatch, this.cardId);
  final DatabaseService _db = new DatabaseService(Firestore.instance);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Card(
        color: Colors.grey[900],
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "${nextMatch.upcomingTeam1}",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white60),
            ),
            Text(
              '-',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white60),
            ),
            Text(
              "${nextMatch.upcomingTeam2}",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white60),
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
              onPressed: () {
                showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return AlertDialog(
                        title: Text(
                          'Biztos?',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                        ),
                        content: Text("Ki akarod törölni a meccset?"),
                        actions: [
                          FlatButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                'Nem',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                              )),
                          FlatButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                deleteMatch(cardId);
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                'Igen',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
                              ))
                        ],
                      );
                    });
              },
              color: Colors.white60,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> deleteMatch(id) async {
    await Firestore.instance.collection("upcomings").document(id).delete();
  }
}
```

this is the code for the page itself:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:foci_dev/model/next_matches.dart';
import 'package:foci_dev/pages/new_match_page.dart';
import 'package:foci_dev/service/database_service.dart';
import 'package:foci_dev/ui/delete_card.dart';

import 'main_page.dart';

class DeletePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DeletePageState createState() => _DeletePageState();
  final DatabaseService databaseService;

  DeletePage(this.databaseService);
}

class _DeletePageState extends State<DeletePage> {
  DatabaseService _databaseService = DatabaseService(Firestore.instance);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text(
          'Foci-admin',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white60),
        ),
        leading: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.edit,
              color: Colors.white60,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => NewMatch(this._databaseService),
                  ));
            },
            tooltip: 'Meccsek hozzáadása',
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.home,
                color: Colors.white60,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => MainPage(),
                    ));
              },
              tooltip: 'Eredmény',
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection("upcomings")
            .orderBy('createdAt')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          return snapshot.hasData
              ? Container(
                  color: Colors.grey[850],
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        DocumentSnapshot upcomings =
                            snapshot.data.documents[index];
                        UpcomingMatch upcomingMatch = UpcomingMatch(
                            upcomings["upcomingTeam1"],
                            upcomings["upcomingTeam2"]);
                        return DeleteCard(upcomingMatch,
                            snapshot.data.documents[index].documentId);
                      }),
                )
              : Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help, I know I should show code I tried, but I am really new to Flutter and Firebase, and I really don't know how to start with this. My only thoughts were that I need to somehow pass the document idto the DeleteCard class, but I got stuck here, because I do not know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for cloud_firestore version 0.14.0+1

You can pass the snapshot.data.documents[index].id or snapshot.data.documents[index].documentID (for older version) to DeleteCard widget and then use that to delete the card from the Firestore.

```
DeleteCard(upcomingMatch , snapshot.data.documents[index].id)

                           OR

DeleteCard(upcomingMatch , snapshot.data.documents[index].documentID) // older version
```

The DeleteCard constructor should look like this

```
DeleteCard(this.nextMatch , this.cardId);
```

And upon getting confirmation from the AlertDialog call deleteMatch(cardId)

```
 Future<void> deleteMatch(id) async{
   await Firestore.instance.collection("upcomings").doc(id).delete();
                          
                            OR
   //older version
   await Firestore.instance.collection("upcomings").document(id).delete(); 

  }
```

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question to how my code is now, and  I get this error: 
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
I/flutter ( 7565): Class 'DocumentSnapshot' has no instance getter 'documentId'.
I/flutter ( 7565): Receiver: Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'
I/flutter ( 7565): Tried calling: documentId
How can I fix this?

Comment: What is your cloud_firestore version ?

Comment: type ID in caps in snapshot.data.documents[index].documentID

Comment: 0.13.7, but everything seems to break if I update it

Comment: @Bennett567 You are typing documentId type documentID

Comment: @Bennett567 If it works then kindly upvote the answer